# How to display the top 5 variable names with largest value in 10 variables in php?

Tags: php

How to display the top 5 cookie names with largest value in it from 10 cookie variables in php ?

Its not a array, i have stored values in 10 separate cookie names and i need to display the names of the cookie ( not value )

iv 10 pages, so i need to display top 5 pages with maximum visit. so i increment $_COOKIE[pr1] in page 1 each time its loaded. now i have 10 cookies pr1,pr2 etc....

Comment: bad code ......

Comment: "Its not a array, i have stored values in 10 separate cookie" — Why isn't it an array? PHP puts cookies in `$_COOKIE` by default.

Comment: iv 10 pages, so i need to display top 5  pages with maximum visit. so i increment $_COOKIE[pr1] in page 1 each time its loaded. now i have 10 cookies pr1,pr2 etc....

Answer (score 0):

You will not get what you want , Cookie saved in the customer's Browser.So Customer 1 and customer 2 will have different cookie value with the same name.

Yes, you can get cookie value and do ++ and store it back to customer 1's computer but it will NOT show in customer 2's cookie

Also as Quentin pointed out ,$_Cookie is indeed an array , you should able to access directly using $_COOKIE['pr1'], you can even "foreach" them.

The correct approach is 1 file ,2 Database, stored on your server, save data from all clients